# Generate Barcode in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created one web application using MVC Framework,
we want to generate multiple barcode for Item, 
each and every barcode should be unique.
we are using Asp.net c# MVC 5.0
Without Image and External Fonts.
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to create an onscreen barcode without using fonts or images?

Comment: Like this: https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Multifunctional-Barcode-Generator-with-jQuery-Html5-Canvas-JsBarcode.html ?

Comment: Why dont you use @Neil suggested ? or do you want a C# solution ?

Comment: yes , this type barcode, but i want to generate without any 3rd party exe.

Comment: "... i want to generate without any 3rd party exe" why?

Comment: If you don't want to use any 3rd party libraries, then I suggest you start looking at wikipedia on how barcodes work and then get the ISO documents, then you can use GDI+ to draw lines on a `Graphics` surface.  Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look step by step.

Step 1: Download QRCODE GENERATOR LIBRARY from onbarcode.com.

Step 2: Open Visual Studio - Create New Project - Windows Form.

Step 3: Add reference to OnBarcode.Barcode.Winforms.dll.

Step 4: Design form with some input fields for accepting data to encode and the targeted location to save barcode generated image.

Step 5: To generate Barcode as well as Qrcode images write two differen methods as follows.

```
    private void GenerateBacode(string _data, string _filename)
    {
        Linear barcode = new Linear();
        barcode.Type = BarcodeType.CODE11;
        barcode.Data = _data;
        barcode.drawBarcode(_filename);
    }
    private void GenerateQrcode(string _data, string _filename)
    {
        QRCode qrcode = new QRCode();
        qrcode.Data = _data;
        qrcode.DataMode = QRCodeDataMode.Byte;
        qrcode.UOM = UnitOfMeasure.PIXEL;
        qrcode.X = 3;
        qrcode.LeftMargin = 0;
        qrcode.RightMargin = 0;
        qrcode.TopMargin = 0;
        qrcode.BottomMargin = 0;
        qrcode.Resolution = 72;
        qrcode.Rotate = Rotate.Rotate0;
        qrcode.ImageFormat = ImageFormat.Gif;
        qrcode.drawBarcode(_filename);
    }
```

Conclusion:

In this way you can generate barcode and qrcode images in C#. Output will look like bellow

Barcode:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhzBE.png

Qrcode:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhzBE.png

Comment: No 3rd party libraries allowed !